# iOS 6.1 and above using ARC having a leak

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I am implementing a simple application for iOS 6.1 and above 
I am using iOS SDK 6.1 and ARC enabled in my project.

when I run analyze inside the xCode it doesn't find anything , but when I transferred my app(simulator) to instruments it found a leak of 128 bytes called

```
Malloc 128 bytes 0x7f95724139d0
```

the question is: How do I know where it happens inside my application

I did read this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html

But when I click on cycle it is empty :( ,
also StackTrace says :

```
    "No stack trace available    for this leak;it maybe allocated before the 
Allocation instrument was attached.
```

However I started the instruments before I run my app .
I guess I am doing something wrong here,
Can someone please help finding the part of code that causing leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your app on an actual device and then check again.

I have seen "phantom" leaks from the simulator before.

You should always test performance and memory issues on a real device rather than the simulator.

Note that a once-per-lifetime leak of 128 bytes is like a sink faucet that leaks a single drop of water after it's turned off. It's totally insignificant and can be safely ignored. The only time a leak that small is a concern is when it happens over and over. Like every time through a loop. In that case a 128 byte leak would be bad.

Comment: it happens 1 time somewhere in first 2 secs of application running, strange things are I am not using any CRefs(idk how to call them those manual allocations that ARC not supports) anywhere in my menu ,
in the places I do use them it doesnt cause any leaks.
However when I ran instruments yesterday the leak was 360 bytes and it says it was OS_Dispatch something , I didnt change anything since then , and tried to read info online,today I decided to ask on SO but now it is 128 bytes leak that it cant even find.